# ¿Por qué contains(".") es 'true' pero split(".") me da un array vacío?

Tags: java, string, regex, double

Tomemos este método:

```
public static void getDecimalPart(double n) {
    int decimales = 0;

    // convertimos el valor a string
    String decimalPartString = String.valueOf(n);

    // comprobamos si contiene punto de decimales
    if (decimalPartString.contains(".")) { 
        // lo partimos y lo ponemos en un array
        String[] doubleArray = decimalPartString.split(".");
        // calculamos los decimales
        decimales = (int) (Double.valueOf(doubleArray[1]) * (Math.pow(10, doubleArray[1].length()-2)));
    }

    // imprimimos
    System.out.println("El numero " + n + " tiene " + decimales + " decimales");
}
```

Comprueba si la cadena `contains(".")`  y en caso afirmativo hace `split(".")`... entonces.... ¿por qué cuando ejecuto?:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    getDecimalPart(1.25698);
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>       at q1607.Q38239413.getDecimalPart(Q38239413.java:25)
>       at q1607.Q38239413.main(Q38239413.java:14)

Depurando incluso me desconcierta aún más ya que el array esta totalmente vacío, no da el `IOOB` por pedir la posición 1 y que no exista, sino que:

```
doubleArray = []
```

**¿Qué no estoy viendo o que me estoy olvidando?**, estoy seguro que es algo totalmente obvio pero no lo veo....

---

Cosas que he probado:

- Usar coma.
- Usar el símbolo decimal del sistema:

  ```
  DecimalFormat format=(DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getInstance();
  DecimalFormatSymbols symbols=format.getDecimalFormatSymbols();
      char sep=symbols.getDecimalSeparator();
  ```
- Al final he hecho el método diferente, pero sigo con la intriga de *qué* está pasando.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Por que en el split la cadena que estas pasando es una expresion regular (regex) y dentro de las expresiones regulares el punto `"."` tiene un significado especial. Si quieres usarlo como un punto tienes que escaparlo `"\\."`

Mientras que el método `contains` no pide una regex sino un `String` y por eso funciona como esperas.

En java quedaría algo así:

```
String[] palabras = linea.split("\\.");
```

Por ampliar un poco la respuesta, en las expresiones regulares el punto es un comodín, lo que significa que sirve para capturar cualquier caracter. Tienes más info en [RegexOne](http://regexone.com/lesson/wildcards_dot)

Comment: Hola @Daniel, tienes razón, antes he quitado la etiqueta `regex` pero ya la he vuelto a añadir, disculpa por mi error. Buena respuesta! Básicamente se tiene que escapar el `.` pero creo que tora manera es en lugar de utilziar un string, utilziar un split con el `char` del punto tal que así: `split('.')` de esta manera ya no es regex (creo) :)

Comment: Lo de la etiqueta me habia dejado descolocado jaja, pero no pasa nada, no problemo.
El truco de usarlo como char no lo conocía, nunca lo he probado! Está bien saberlo!

Comment: aceptada miquel, ideal el *add-on* del significado del punto y link de las regex... Eso si..... vaya pajareo por mi parte, la verdad, no se que me ha pasado, las mañanas son muy duras xDDDDDDDDD

Comment: Me llamo Daniel jajaja. Si que estás fino in the morning xd

Comment: @Daniel lo dicho, tengo que dormir más... `:P`

Answer (score -1):

Como menciona Luiggi Mendoza, el metodo `split(String regex)` recibe como parámetro una cadena que representa una expresión regular. Otro método alternativo para que te tome el punto `.` como caracter de separación puedes aplicar lo siguiente:

```
double valor = 8545200054.846546;

String ValorStrExponente = String.valueOf(valor);
String ValorStrCompleto = BigDecimal.valueOf(valor).toPlainString();

String[] PartesValor = ValorStrCompleto.split("[.]");

System.out.println("Valor convertido directo a String: "+ValorStrExponente);
System.out.println("Parte entera: "+PartesValor[0]);
System.out.println("Parte decimal: "+PartesValor[1]);
```

Si pones los corchetes encerrando al punto, te lo toma explicitamente como criterio de separación de la cadena. Tambien recomiendo utilizar el método `toPlainString(double valor)` de la clase `BigDecimal`, ya que si el valor `double` que estas tratando de separar en partes es muy grande y lo conviertes directo con `String.valueOf(double valor)`, te dará como resultado un valor exponencial. Si corres el código anterior te genera la siguiente salida:

```
Valor convertido directo a String: 8.545200054846546E9
Parte entera: 8545200054
Parte decimal: 846546
```